# Feign endpoint called within DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor is not caught by Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, feign

I have a runnable task like so:

```
public class Computation implements Runnable {
    FeignClientInterface feignClient;

    public Computation(FeignClientInterface feignClient) {
        this.feignClient = feignClient;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        feignClient.status(authorizationHeader, "Ready");
    }
}
```

I am calling it inside a `DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor` like so:

```
Computation computation = new Computation();
DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor delegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor = new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
delegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor.submit(computation);
```

This project has a dependency that contains multiple `Filter` classes to handle exceptions. They are enabled by an annotation that imports `@Configuration` classes that create `@Bean` for each filter. This annotation is added to the main class of the project.

These filters work perfectly when I call the endpoint normally (not asynchonously/inside a runnable). However, when I execute the code like the one above, it never reaches the filters anymore (regardless of whether an exception is thrown or not).

the `Filter` class itself does not seem to mention whether it has a specific issue with asynchronous tasks so I am at a loss as to why the Filters are not triggered.